# Text Fields - onLoad 'Username/Password', onClick/Focus Changes Color, onKeyDown Disappears (Similar to Twitter)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a login with a simple email-field and password-field.
I have all the basics of what I want but I can't put them all together.
What I want is the same look of the TEXT FIELDS as twitter.
What I mean by that is when the two fields aren't selected they say "Email" and "Password"
But when they are selected the text is unselectable and the cursor appears in the front.
As soon as you type they disappear and whatever you type appears.

The easiest solution is just adding a background image to them.
I have done this but do not want this look.  Its not precise enough for me.

If you are confused with what I am looking for go to twitter and look at their LOG IN fields where they say username/password.  I want that same look.  Any help is GREATLY appreciated.
Thank You.

Please given in HTML, CSS or JavaScript if possible but any solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clearInput(this) {

    var currValue = document.getElementById(this).value;
    if (currValue != '') {
        currValue = '';
    }
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="login" value="email" class="input-box" onchange="clearInput(this);">
<input type="password" id="password" value="password" class="input-box" onchange="clearInput(this);">
```

This is not tested by should work....

You can use any number of JS events so you will have to shoose the one which gives the timings you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You, but I already got this far... I was looking for this but the text doesn't disappear until you type, which I previously used onKeyDown... but I didn't want the text selectable either but this made another problem. Any more suggestions? If you check out twitter, the log 'effect' is exactly what I want.  Specifically watch the words 'Username' and 'Password' when you click, then type.

Comment: Hi there it looks as though twitter use a span to hold the text within a div containing the input field. this will listen for a keydown and then make the span.innerHTML = ''; Hope this helps. Will try to write an answer later on today.

Comment: So they are just positioning a span over the text field?

Comment: yes, i imagine absolute positioning with the parent div being relative.

Comment: Okay, I may try that.  Absolute position the span over the input field is what you're saying then, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `placeholder="your placeholder"` on the inputs?

then you can use fall back jquery scripts to provide the functionality for older browsers

Comment: A bit more searching results in : https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder

Comment: Yeah IE is quite a pain, but I guess that's where these jquery scripts come in handy, just include the script in the header using IE conditioal tags, and that should provide the placeholder function to all those older browsers, down to about IE6 :)

Answer (score 0):

First, the javascript.... if you're using jQuery, this should take your text fields and remove the values in them (Email, etc) when click in them and bring them into focus.

```
 $(function() {
    $('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
     $(this).val('');
    });
 });
```

Your html should look similar to this....

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="email"/>
<input type="password" name="password" value="password" />
```

To get the border highlight effect, you can add some css....note that this example will add a green border around *all* inputs (text fields, text areas, etc) when they are focused. You can change this by using id's or specifying the input type.

```
input:focus { border: 1px solid green;}
```

if you're trying to get the default text to disappear on keydown instead of on focus, one approach is to give each of the inputs an id, and then use a flag to check to see if the event handler (e.g the text disappearing) has already fired, on each of the ids...

```
 $(function() {
    var passFired = false;
    var emailFired = false;

    var email = $('#email');
    var pass = $('#password');

    email.keydown(function() {
        if(!efired){
            efired = true;
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });


    pass.keydown(function() {
        if(!pfired){
            pfired = true;
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank You, but I already got this far... I was looking for this but the text doesn't disappear until you type, which I previously used onKeyDown... but I didn't want the text selectable either but this made another problem.  Any more suggestions?